# Style in OpenLayers shows invalid characters on some computers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, style, font

I have a layer in OpenLayers, which I style for font color. However, on some computers, the texts show with special characters, a blurred, confusing text that cannot be read. In others, without any lateralization, it shows all the text (numbers) correct. Does anyone know what can it be? If it is some computer specific setting and how can I resolve the style in OpenLayers to show same on all computers?

[CODE STYLE]. Here is the style code with red padding

```
function style_cadastro_lote_busca (feature, cor, espessura) {
    var cod_setor = feature.get('COD_SETOR')
    var cod_quadra = feature.get('COD_QUADRA')
    var cod_lote = feature.get('COD_LOTE')
    
    var cod_sql =  cod_lote 
    
    var numeracao = (feature.get('NUM_NUMERACAO') !== null ? feature.get('NUM_NUMERACAO') : '')
    var area_terreno = (feature.get('QTD_AREA_TERRENO') !== null ? feature.get('QTD_AREA_TERRENO') : '')
    
    
    cod_sql =  cod_sql + '\n nº: ' + numeracao + '\n ' + area_terreno + ' m²'
    
    
    var style_lote = new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0,58,20, 0.050980392156862744 )', //rgba(0,58,20,0.60) 
                opacity: 1
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: cor,
                width: espessura,
            }),
    
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text:  cod_sql, 
                font: 'bold 14px Calibri,sans-serif', 
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ width: 2.5, color: [255,255,255] }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({  color: 'red' }),
            }),
        });
    return style_lote           
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your image shows text with red fill and white stroke.  If the stroke is too wide it will make the fill illegible.

Comment: @Mike I've amended the post, with the red padded style code. Note that not all texts show wrong. And not on all computers.

Comment: Full colors without any alpha are usually OK as the fill should be on top of the stroke.  There is one report of a problem which looks similar to yours on specific combinations of OpenLayers and Windows versions (although I suspect it may be browser and hardware combination, not the Windows version) https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14921